# Hide <tr> containing specific ID's

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I have multiple tables on one page and an array of numbers from `array_keys`.

I have given each `<tr>` an incremental ID, starting at 0. If my array returns 0,1,3,5 I would want the `<tr>` with an ID of 2 and 4 to hide. Usually I would use CSS and apply a style: display=none.

I presume I need to use jQuery .find() within a array loop such as this:

```
$arr = array_keys($floor_item, $po); //floor_item is my array & po is the value I'm searching 

 foreach($arr as $key => $item){
 print "<tr id='" . $item . "'><td>" . $item . "</td></tr>"; //this will show me the id's I want

//just guessing here
$( "tr" ).find( "$item" ).hide();

}
```

Comment: Solely numeric IDs are a HTML 5 feature... Best you prefix them and match on the prefix using `$('tr[id^=myprefix]')

Comment: you can not use jQuery in php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use client side code to hide the elements, try something like this:

```
var jsArray = [<?php echo(implode(",", $ids_you_want_to_show_array); ?>];
$("#your_table_id tr").hide();
$.each(jsArray, function(key, value) {
    $("#tr_" + value).show();
});
```

Assuming your td's ids are "tr_0", "tr_1", and so on.
By the way, don't use numbers as ID.

Comment: I can get this code working but only for the first table on the page. I have used the code: `<?php $floor_item=unserialize($row['floor_item']);
 $tr_ids = array_keys($floor_item, $po);
 ?>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var jsArray = [<?php echo(implode(",", $tr_ids)); ?>];
console.log(jsArray)
$("#blank > tbody  > tr").hide();

$.each(jsArray, function(key, value) {

    $("#tr_" + value).show();
});

});
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr = array_keys(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); 
$i == 0;
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if ($i%2 != 0 || $i == 0) {
        //this will show me the id's I want
        print "<tr id='pref_" . $item . "'><td>" . $item . "</td></tr>"; 
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Anyway, you need to learn php from basics before you start to use that.

In arrays, if you want key/value pairs you can define it like:

```
$array = array(
    'key1' => 'value',
    7 => 'other value',
    ...
);
```

or

```
$array['key1'] = 'value';
$array[7] = 'other value';
```

And as i mentioned, you can not use jQuery/javascript code in your php code.